# python using for loop in def function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, structure

I am trying to get documents created in past 7 days in DB collection.

```
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
today = datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Seoul'))
for i in range(0, 7):
    target = today - timedelta(days = i)
    week = target.strftime(fmt)
    hot_posts = list(db.collection.find({'date': week}, {'_id': False}).sort('like', -1))
    print(hot_posts)
```

this gives me correct document set that I am looking for from DB.

but when I insert this in def function, it doesn't work.

```
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
today = datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Seoul'))
@app.route('/api/list/hot', methods=['GET'])
def show_hot():
    for i in range(0, 7):
        target = today - timedelta(days=i)
        week = target.strftime(fmt)
        hot_posts = list(db.collection.find({'date': week}, {'_id': False}).sort('like', -1))
        return jsonify({'hot_posts': hot_posts})
```

I don't think I am fully understanding how to use def in correct structure.
what is the correct format of using def in python for this case?
Do I need to put some variable before for loop and set it like variable=[] to get the result of for loop and put it into the variable that the def function can use?
and do I need to put some for loop variable into () of def function?

something like this?

```
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
today = datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Seoul'))
@app.route('/api/list/hot', methods=['GET'])
def show_hot(range, list):
    hot_posts = []
    for i in range(0, 7):
        target = today - timedelta(days=i)
        week = target.strftime(fmt)
        hot_posts = list(db.collection.find({'date': week}, {'_id': False}).sort('like', -1))
    return jsonify({'hot_posts': hot_posts})
```

Comment: Maybe you want `yield` instead of `return`.

Comment: `return` terminates the function, so the for loop only runs one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a blank dictionary and update keys and values of it on iteration and then return the resultant dictionary. I haven't tested the this code but I think it should work fine.

```py
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
today = datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Seoul'))
@app.route('/api/list/hot', methods=['GET'])
def show_hot():
    all_hot_posts = {}
    for i in range(0, 7):
        target = today - timedelta(days=i)
        week = target.strftime(fmt)
        hot_posts = list(db.collection.find({'date': week}, {'_id': False}).sort('like', -1))
        all_hot_posts.update({'hot_posts'+str(i+1): hot_posts})
    return jsonify(all_hot_posts)
```

In python functions we do not define keywords as arguments. They are interpreted just like normal script.

Comment: I see how your answer send variables in for loop to function but still not working. I  use PyCharm and when I put show_hot(range, list), the range and list in for loop become like variables(originally purple color = working like "print", change to sky blue color = variables) which seems to change its functionality. maybe..

Comment: I found the error this is due to because range and list are defined keywords in python. I have done some revisions to code you can retry it.

Comment: First, thank you, your updated answer brings data from DB! 
Second, however the format it comes doesn't match my ajax call to append in my html.
Are there ways to manipulate with {} and [] ? because this was for a week volume of data and I am trying to make month, quarter, half-year, and year. I want to use the same ajax format for all those periods. the current result looks like {'hot_posts1' : [{doc1}, {doc2}...{doc100}], ... 'hot_posts7' : [{doc701}...{doc799}]}
but I want in format of [{doc1}...{doc799)] this way I do not need to change ajax call format for all different periods

Comment: I should look up how to flattening list of dictionaries in list.