# python flatten/unwrap list of dictionaries in list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, iteration

I have list of dictionaries in list like below

```
A = [[{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}],[{...}],[{...}],[],[],[{'x': '25', 'z':'26'}]]
```

7 lists of dictionaries inside a list "A" (data from 7days)
[python using for loop in def function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68109027/python-using-for-loop-in-def-function)

some lists of dictionaries inside A has data, some doesn't

I want to flatten/unwrap like this into a different list B

```
B = [{'a': '1', 'b': '2', ..., 'x': '25', 'z':'26'}]
```

as a list of dictionaries.

I have tried(with corresponding imports):

```
B = (list(itertools.chain(*A)))

B = [item for sublist in A for item in sublist]

B = [dict(chain(*map(dict.items, d.values()))) for d in A]
```

Above 3 flattening/unwrapping methods give me an empty list [] as a result.
I want to do this because just one list will fit to my ajax append format in html
that will be applied for data sets for month, quarter, half-year, and year as well.(I also need to flatten 365 lists of dictionaries in a list with for loop is used to create this list)

Am I using above method wrong?

Does flattening/unwrapping has to follow the each unorganized list of lists' structure?

Is it better not to create the unorganized list like list A by changing for loop from [python using for loop in def function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68109027/python-using-for-loop-in-def-function) ?

EDIT: I separated unflatten list(A) and flatten list(B) in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.chain()` and dict comprehension:

```
A = [[{1:1, 2:2}], [], [{3:3}], [{8:8}], [], [], [{9:9}]]
b = itertools.chain(*A)
{k:v for x in b for k,v in x.items()}
```

Expected result:
`{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 8: 8, 9: 9}`

More about itertools: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-itertools/

More about dict comprehension: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary-comprehension

Comment: Thank you for the help, I found my code to do the job that I wanted through not putting into another list which made me not needing to unwrap. I was looking for a harder solution the whole day and found that was putting data into unnecessary extra[] after a nap